# reduce code lines saving in viewstate properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I have a custom server control that has a lot of properties - each of them save their state in viewstate:

```
    public Color XXX
    {
        get
        {
            return (Color)ViewState["XXX"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["XXX"] = value;
        }
    }
```

This takes a lot of space - is there a way to reduce the number of lines in the code?

Comment: Are you worried about the amount of space it takes up in your code files, or more about the number of statements?

Answer (score 5):

Remove some of the white space?

```
public Color XXX
{
    get { return (Color)ViewState["XXX"]; }
    set { ViewState["XXX"] = value; }
}
```

Honestly I wouldn't concern yourself with the amount of vertical space your code is taking up, if that is truly what your question is about. Use `#region`s to group your properties. You can then collapse the region if you don't want to see it.

```
#region ViewState Properties

... your properties

#endregion
```